# String word reverse in Java giving wrong result?

Tags: java, string, reverse

Here is my code to print string characters reversed in Java without using any API. But it's not working properly. Can anybody help me to correct it?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "I am test";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Character c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c != ' ') {
            result = c + result;
        } else {
            System.out.println(result + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

It is giving output "test amtest", while the output should be "test am I".

Please help me to get exact output without using predefined methods or API's.

Comment: You are using a lot of predefined methods and APIs there: `length`, `charAt`, `println`. You are also using predefined operators `-`, `>`, `--`, `!=`, `+`. Can you clarify why those are allowed and others are not? And more importantly, what constraints do you have that force you to not be able to use the predefined methods and APIs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are four problems with your implementation:

- You do not go all the way down to zero,
- You put an end of line after each printout in the loop,
- You do not print the "tail" result after the loop is over, and
- You do not clear out `result` after printing it in the loop.

Fixing these issues will give you proper output ([demo](http://ideone.com/NNSmvC)).

Answer (score 4):

try

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "I am test";
    String result = "";
    int start=input.length()-1;
    for (int i = input.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
        Character c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            for(int j=i+1;j<=start;j++)
                result +=input.charAt(j);
            result+=" ";
            start=i-1;
        }
        else if (i==0)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=start;j++)
                result +=input.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}//It is giving output as test amtest
//output should be : test am I
```

Comment: please observe the solution given by dasblinkenlight,a

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "I am test";
    String result = "";

    String[] frags = input.split(" ");
    for (int i = frags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(frags[i] + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try recursion as well -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "I am test";
    List<String> listOfString = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));

    System.out.println(reverseString(listOfString));

}

private static String reverseString(List<String> input) {
    int n = input.size();
    String result = "";
    if(input.isEmpty()){
        return result;
    }

    if(n>1){
   /*adding last element with space and changes the size of list as well
        test + " " + [am, I] 
        test + " " + am + " " + [I]*/

        result = input.get(n-1) + " " + reverseString(input.subList(0, n-1));
    }else{
        result = input.get(n-1);
    }               
    return result;

}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String input = "I am test";
    String result="";
    for(int i=input.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        result=result+input.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: If you format your code it will be much more readable and helpful to the OP